# is this act of worship actually Rewarded?

Tags: bidah, hajj, travelling

a Man from my country justa  a couple of days ago, he  began his 218 day journey to Makkah from India (kerala) BY FOOT, without using any mode of transportation. He thinks by doing so , he'll get extra rewrded and if he dies in the proces he'll be dying in a righteous cause.  and people all around are Praising and congratulating him for his courage and sacrifice.

Is this actually an act of worship?? that is rewarded ?

I know walking to masjid has higher reward than going to masjid by a car.. if it's near.. but to hajj too? when it's too risky?... is this actually Rewarded??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This might not be an act of worship. Allah knows best. But to qualify as an act of worship one should fulfil below two conditions:

1. al-Ikhlaas (Sincerity)
2. al-Mutabaa’a (According to Sunnah)

Two conditions must be fulfilled in order for an act of worship to be accepted; the first of the two conditions is that the act of worship must be done **sincerely** for Allaah, and secondly the act of worship must be in **agreement with the Sunnah** of the Messenger(ﷺ).

Incase of this man he might not be fulfilling the second condition. His action is not according to sunnah. There is no need to take a harmful approach when easier methods of transportations are available.

> The Prophet(ﷺ), said, “Make things easy and do not make things
> difficult. Give glad tidings and do not frighten them away.” Source:
> Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 69, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 1734

In another Hadith.

> ‘Ubadah ibn al-Samit reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and
> blessings be upon him, issued a decree, “Do not cause harm or return
> harm.” Source: Sunan Ibn Mājah 2340